# Slider navigation buttons will not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a pure CSS slider and now I am trying to add in navigation buttons. I want all four buttons to remain seen on any image and then when one clicks on the first button it takes them to the first image.

Right now the radio buttons I have are only showing per image and for some reason above the images. I am wanting all four to `display: inline`. Then for the correct slide to show when a button is clicked.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
#company-slider-section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 800px;
}

div#slider {
 width: 100%;
 /*max-width: 1000px;*/
 overflow: hidden; 
}
div#slider figure {
 position: relative;
 width: 400%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 text-align: left;
 animation: 20s company-slider infinite; 
}
@keyframes company-slider { 
 0%  { left: 0%; }
 20% { left: 0%; }
 25% { left: -100%; }
 45% { left: -100%; }
 50% { left: -200%; }
 70% { left: -200%; } 
 75% { left: -300%; }
 95% { left: -300%; }
 100% { left: -300%; } 
}
div#slider figure img {
 width: 25%;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}
/*div#slider figure:hover { animation-play-state:paused; }*/
div#slider li {
 list-style: none;
}
div#slider label {
    background-color: #111;
    bottom: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    width: .5em;
    z-index: 10;
}
#slider li:nth-child(1) label {
    left: .5em;
}
#slider li:nth-child(2) label {
    left: 2em;
}
#slider li:nth-child(3) label {
    left: 3.5em;
}
#slider li:nth-child(4) label {
    left: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
     <li>
     <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slide" checked>
     <label for="slide1"></label>
      <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-139669245.jpg" alt>
     </li>
     <li>
     <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slide">
     <label for="slide2"></label>
      <img src="http://i.cbc.ca/1.3376224.1450794847!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/4x3_620/tundra-tea-toss.jpg" alt>
     </li>
     <li>
     <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slide">
     <label for="slide3"></label>
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/22804/pexels-photo.jpg" alt>
     </li>
     <li>
     <input type="radio" id="slide4" name="slide">
     <label for="slide4"></label>
      <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-139669245.jpg" alt>
     </li>
    </figure>
   </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/justinwyllie/8kgjy56r/ . How are you actually planning for the buttons to display their image when clicked? It looks like you were planning for the selection of a radio button to somehow draw its image into view? Am I right about that? f you want a pure CSS solution with no JavaScript at all you might be able to do something with the :checked pseudo selector of the radio buttons and CSS. When button1 is :checked show image 1 - hide the rest? But why would you not want to use JavaScript?. Your radio buttons are showing one per image because that is what you html is doing.

Comment: I am open to javacript for the navigation buttons. I just wanted to keep the transitions purely css.

Comment: @JustinWyllie How could I do it with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/justinwyllie/8kgjy56r/

```
$('input[name="grp"]').click(function() {
  button = $(this).attr('id');
  id = button.replace('slide','');
  pos = (id - 1) * 100;
   $('div#slider figure').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
   $('div#slider figure').removeClass('figure2');
   posStr = '-' + pos + '%';
   $('.figure').css('left', posStr );

});

$('img').click(function() {
   $('div#slider figure').addClass('figure2');
  $('div#slider figure').css('animation-play-state', 'running');

})
```

Well - jQuery. (Just use native DOM methods if you don't like to use jQuery (-:).

Click the image to re-start the animation.

The tricky thing turned out to be that if you have an animation applied to an element you cannot then just set the style of (at least) the property being animated (in this case left) so I couldn't just pause the animation hand control over to the buttons and then resume the animation. I had to remove the animation then add it back.

A more thorough way of doing this appears to be getting a handle on the cssRules and then controlling the animation keyframes with JavaScript. But I didn't have time for this and, anyway, am not sure if it is production ready.

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions on this, why doesn't the slider keep transitioning when one of the inputs is selected? Also how could I add an active style to one of the buttons when selected?

Comment: For the active button, I made a class called 'active' and put this line of code ` $('.control-button').addClass('active');` under ` $('.control-button').addClass('active');` It changes all of the buttons though.

Comment: I've updated my Fiddle and tried to put in some explaining comments.